# Why isn't my backtick in Ruby working?

Tags: ruby, bash

I have this code

```
`ifconfig`

%x(ifconfig)

system("ifconfig")
```

When I run it, only the "system("ifconfig")" works. I know it because I run them separately first.

Comment: what do you mean by only "system("ifconfig")" works? any errors?

Comment: @EvgeniyRyzhkov That's the problem. No errors at all. I don't even know what went wrong. The first two methods shows nothing. Not even an error. The third method shows the output of "ifconfig" in the console.

Comment: @user1535147 What they mean is: what happened vs. what did you expect to happen?

Comment: My bad, I should have done more research instead of relying on one link(http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands). I expected the program to execute the "ifconfig" command three times. I understand my mistakes now. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No, you were right; it executed `ifconfig` three times.  But the first two returned the output of the command as a string, which your code didn't do anything with. It's like running the program `2+2` and wondering why it didn't output `4`.  
    The third version just let the output go to stdout, so you saw that one - but on the other hand, there was no way for your program to access that output and do anything with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backticks and %x variants return the output of the result in a variable. `system()` will invoke the command and return `!!return_code`.

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > `ifconfig`
 => "eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>..."

1.9.3p327 :002 > %x(ifconfig)
 => "eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>..."

1.9.3p327 :003 > system("ifconfig")
eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
...
 => true
```